# Are copy constructors defined implicitly always, or only when they are used?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

Consider the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class A
{
private:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> _vals;
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  //A a2(a);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiler A compiles this without issue unless I uncomment out the line `A a2(a);` at which point it complains about the copy constructor for `std::unique_ptr` being deleted, and therefore I can't copy construct `A`. Compiler B, however, makes that complaint even if I leave that line commented out. That is, compiler A only generates an implicitly defined copy constructor when I actually try to use it, whereas compiler B does so unconditionally. Which one is correct? Note that if I were to have used `std::unique_ptr<int> _vals;` instead of `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> _vals;` both compilers correctly implicitly delete both copy constructor and assignment operator (`std::unique_ptr` has a explicitly deleted copy constructor, while `std::vector` does not).

(Note: Getting the code to compile in compiler B is easy enough - just explicitly delete the copy constructor and assignment operator, and it works correctly. That isn't the point of the question; it is to understand the correct behavior.)

Comment: [This copy constructor reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) might help you.

Comment: Which compiler is compiler B? Feel free to use the real name of the compilers you are using.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which are compilers A and B?

Comment: Compiler A is GNU 7.1, compiler B is various versions of the Intel compiler

Comment: I can't repro with any intel compiler [here](https://godbolt.org/g/fUi8T4)... Are you using some very old version?

Comment: The compiler should not give you an error on a comment.  If it does it has a bug.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Now that you mentioned that, it only appears to happen on the Intel compiler on Windows - when I try it using the Intel compiler on Linux, it works correctly... That is a bit bizarre to me. I am using the latest version of the compiler (18.3) that is out

Comment: Please use https://gcc.godbolt.org and share the link which demonstrates error with icc. Generating error with commented out line is a showstopper bug for any decent compiler.

Comment: @R_Kapp Are you specifying the C++ standard version explicitly or allowing the compiler to choose?

Comment: @NathanOliver: It's not generating the error on the comment, but on the implicitly generated copy constructor. If I don't uncomment the particular line in question, I never actually call the copy constructor, and GNU 7.1 doesn't generate one. Intel, though (only on Windows, and only when I declare `class A` a DLL export), generates a copy constructor regardless of whether I need it.

Comment: @SergeyA: As I mentioned in another comment, it's only on Windows, and only when I explicitly list `class A` as a DLL export (via, e.g., `class __declspec(dllexport) A`) that this happens. That might have been a clue to me...

Comment: @ZanLynx: I explicitly specify `/Qstd=c++11` (Intel Windows version of `std=c++11`)

Comment: @R_Kapp That is information that should be in the question.  Your "mvce" doesn't represent what you are actually doing.

Comment: @R_Kapp if you are looking for any sensible conversation, you need to provide all those details in MCVE.

Comment: @SergeyA: This is why I left it as "compiler A" and "compiler B" in the question - I'm not looking to see if anyone else can reproduce the issue, I'm looking to see which one is right.

Comment: @R_Kapp MCVE should be provided with 'who is right' questions as well. I am still not convinced your analysis is correct, like I said before, this would be a showstopper bug with the compiler.

Comment: @SergeyA: I guess I don't really care if anyone's "convinced" that I found this? How is that at all relevant to the question? Surely that's something that I would have to take up with Intel support?

Comment: @NathanOliver: That information is tangential to the problem - it is highly relevant if and when I file a bug report against a specific compiler, but it is not relevant to whether the attached program should compile. Being on Windows or Linux (or exporting something or importing something) does not affect the C++ standard of copy constructors.

Comment: Since it only happens when using `__declspec(dllexport)`, that should be part of the MCVE. (Especially if there is a chance that declaring a class for export causes its implicitly defined constructors to be instantiated for the DLL interface.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [[class.copy.ctor]/12](http://eel.is/c++draft/special#class.copy.ctor-12.sentence-1):

> A copy/move constructor that is defaulted and not defined as deleted is *implicitly defined* when it is odr-used ([basic.def.odr]), when it is needed for constant evaluation ([expr.const]), or when it is explicitly defaulted after its first declaration.

`A`'s copy constructor is defaulted, so it's implicitly defined only when it is odr-used. `A a2(a);` is just such an odr-use - so it's that statement that would trigger its definition, that would make the program ill-formed. Until the copy constructor is odr-used, it should not be defined.

Compiler B is wrong to reject the program.

Comment: Your conclusion is true iff * compiler B* rejects the code as it is actually written in the question. Since the comments reveal that *__declspec(dllexport)* is also in the game, I think things might be a little less trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Note: My answer is based on your comment:

> [...] it's only on Windows, and only when I explicitly list class A as a DLL export (via, e.g., class __declspec(dllexport) A) that this happens. [...]

On [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/using-dllimport-and-dllexport-in-cpp-classes) we can learn that declaring a class `dllexport` makes all members exported and required a definition for all of them. I suspect the compiler generates the definitions for all non-`delete`d functions in order to comply with this rule.

As you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404108/issue-with-is-copy-constructible), `std::is_copy_constructible<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>>::value` is actually `true` and I would expect the supposed mechanism (that defines the copy constructor in your case for export purposes) checks the value of this trait (or uses a similar mechanism) instead of actually checking whether it would compile. That would explain why the bahviour is correct when you use `unique_ptr<T>` instead of `vector<unique_ptr<T>>`.

The issue is thus, that `std::vector` actually defines the copy constructor even when it wouldn't compile.

Imho, a `is_copy_constructible` check is sufficient because at the point where your `dllexport` happens you cannot know whether the implicit function will be *odr-used* at the place where you use `dllimport` (possibly even another project). Thus, I wouldn't think of it as a bug in compiler `B`.

Comment: There are times though, where the compiler will inline something from a header in a different project - wouldn't this be a perfect use case for that? I.e., if I don't declare the copy constructor or odr-use it within my module, don't include at compile time - instead, inline it into any module that does odr-use it. To me, that's a perfectly valid fix (especially as an implicitly defined copy constructor should be fairly simple) - would that cause any other issues?

Comment: @R_Kapp: How will the other project know whether you (or your compiler) defined the copy constructor in your `dll` or whether it should generate one "inline" if and only if there is an odr-use? If the definition is in the header file it can be inlined but if the function is implicit you cannot tell at compiler time of project `Y` whether dll `X` ships a definition or not. Since `A`s copy constructor is not implicitly deleted because that of `std::vector` isn't deleted either, an implicit definition should be generated.

Comment: That's a fair point... I suppose an easier fix would be to always inline (and not export) implicitly defined copy constructors. This way, you won't violate ODR (nothing's ever exported), and it is still only defined when it is ever actually odr-used.

Comment: (Feel free to tell me I should ask this as a separate question if you'd prefer) Also, how does this work on Linux with GNU? The class is listed as "for export" there as well, and I'm not getting that function to be generated implicitly. How would that work if I were to use it in another module/project? My guess is that it would do something like what I've suggested above (i.e., inline it always if it's implicit), but there might be some specific differences between the two OSes that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't confirm this behavior (I do not have access to Windows compiler, and OP claims the bug happens with icc on Windows platform), taking the question at it's face value, the answer is - compiler B has a gross bug.

In particular, implicitly-declared copy constructor is defined as deleted, when ...

> T has non-static data members that cannot be copied (have deleted,
>   inaccessible, or ambiguous copy constructors);

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor

Thus, conforming compiler must semantically generate deleted copy-constructor, and successfully compile the program since such constructor never called.

Comment: `std::vector` is copyable, though. As I mention in the question, if I replace `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> _vals` with `std::unique_ptr<int> _vals`, I don't get the issue - `std::unique_ptr` isn't copyable and therefore the copy constructor is correctly implicitly deleted. `std::vector`, which is what the compiler has, though, is copyable.

Comment: @R_Kapp why do you think `std::vector` of `std::unique_ptr`s is copyable?

Comment: @R_Kapp: `std::vector` is not a type. `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>` is not copyable.

Comment: `std::vector<T>` has a copy constructor defined. It is not deleted, inaccessible, or ambiguous. It so happens that the template parameter that it uses in this case (`std::unique_ptr`) is not copyable, but that doesn't change the definition of `std::vector`

Comment: See [this link](https://ideone.com/X5FRld) as evidence that `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>` does not match the description provided in this answer.